# why are browsers not reading my imported modules but node.js does?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, web, module

So I'm new to Typescript,Javascript and the NPM eco-system.
I'm creating a dapp for a client and I'm stuck with an issue that only produces when I try to use some npm packages within browser but not when I run them on node.js.

here is my folder structure (moved everything to root dir for simplicity):
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEuLk.png)

here are the modules I'm trying to import:
[npm packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0ZC3.png)

and here is the error in the browser console(don't get a runtime error when I use the modules with node):
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8BFD.png)

here is the neccessary code to reproduce the problem:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Suteki Hyper Trainoor</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="connect_container">
        <button id="button"><span>Connect Wallet</span></button></body>
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-box">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h2 class="modal-title">Choose a wallet</h2>
                <button class="wallet-btn" id="Phantom">Phantom Wallet</button>
                <button class="wallet-btn" id="Solflare">Solflare Wallet</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-alert">
        <p id="custom-alert-message"></p>
      </div>      
          
      <script type="module" src="loader.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a90c2, #032333);
}

.connect_container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

#button {
  display: flex;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3f6b8e, #5b9dc5);
    border: 1px ridge whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
  
  #button:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5b9dc5, #3f6b8e);
  }
  
  #button span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #button span:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #5b9dc5;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  #button:hover span:after {
    width: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
  }

  .loader {
  border: 4px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 4px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: spin 0.5s linear infinite;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  .modal-box {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #09555c, #022022);
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    animation-name: modalFadeIn;
    animation-duration: 1s;
  
  }
  @keyframes modalFadeIn {
    from {
      transform: translateY(70%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  .modal-title {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;

  }
  
  .modal-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .wallet-btn {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #3A58FF 0%, #3A58FF 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .wallet-btn:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #4967F1 0%, #3A58FF 100%);
  }
  #Solflare{
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
  }

  .custom-alert {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(131, 32, 32);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
  }
```

Typescript:

```
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import {SolflareWalletAdapter} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection} from '@solana/web3.js';

declare global {
    interface Window {
      solana: any;
    }
  }

const button = document.getElementById('button') as HTMLElement;
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal')as HTMLElement;
const phantom = document.getElementById('Phantom')as HTMLElement;
const solflare = document.getElementById('Solflare')as HTMLElement;
const loader = document.createElement('div');
loader.classList.add('loader');




//added this so I can add the import transpiled js and prosuce issue.
//comment this line to rmeove issue
const connection = new Connection('');
//issue-1

//custom alert message
function showAlert(message:string) {
  var customAlert = document.querySelector('.custom-alert') as HTMLElement;
  var customAlertMessage = document.querySelector('#custom-alert-message') as HTMLElement;
  
  customAlertMessage.textContent = message;
  customAlert.style.display = 'block';
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    customAlert.style.display = 'none';
  }, 3000);
}

//connecting to phantom
async function connect_phantom(){
  
  if (!window.solana || !window.solana.isPhantom) {
      // Phantom is not installed
      console.log('lmao')
      showAlert('Phantom wallet extension not installed!') 
      button.style.display = 'flex' 
      loader.style.display = 'none' 
      return
    }
  
    try {
      await window.solana.connect();
      console.log("Connected to Phantom wallet");
      // Do something after connection is established
    
    } catch (err) {
      showAlert('Error while connecting to wallet')
    }
}

//connecting to phantom
async function connect_solflare(){
  
  //if (!window.solana || !window.solana.solflare) {
  //    // Phantom is not installed
  //    showAlert('Solflare wallet extension not installed!')  
  //    button.style.display = 'flex' 
  //    loader.style.display = 'none' 
  //    return   
  //  }
    try {
      console.log(window.solana)
      //const temp= new SolflareWalletAdapter()
      //temp.connect()
      console.log("Connected to Solflare wallet");
      // Do something after connection is established
    
    } catch (err) {
      showAlert('Error while connecting to wallet')
    }
}

button.addEventListener('click', async() => {
    // Hide the button
    button.style.display = 'none';
    loader.style.display = 'flex' 
    
      if ( null === button.parentNode ) {
      throw Error( 'refNode.parentNode is null');
      }
  
    // Add the loading indicator element to the document
    button.parentNode.insertBefore(loader, button.nextSibling);
    setTimeout(() => {
      modal.style.display = 'flex';
    }, 500);

    //await wallet.connect();
});
  
  phantom.addEventListener('click', async() => {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
    await connect_phantom();
  
  });
  solflare.addEventListener('click', async() => {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
    await connect_solflare();
  
  });
```

ts-config file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Save .tsbuildinfo files to allow for incremental compilation of projects. */
    // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./.tsbuildinfo",              /* Specify the path to .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation file. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects. */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "lib": ["es6","DOM"],                                      /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h'. */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using 'jsx: react-jsx*'. */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for 'createElement'. This only applies when targeting 'react' JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
    // "moduleDetection": "auto",                        /* Control what method is used to detect module-format JS files. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "ES6",
    //"rootDir": ".",                                    /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    // "moduleSuffixes": [],                             /* List of file name suffixes to search when resolving a module. */
    //"resolveJsonModule": true,                           /* Enable importing .json files. */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow 'import's, 'require's or '<reference>'s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */

    /* JavaScript Support */
    "allowJs": true,                                     /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from 'node_modules'. Only applicable with 'allowJs'. */

    /* Emit */
    // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
     "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    //"outDir": "build",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have '@internal' in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like '__extends' in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing 'const enum' declarations in generated code. */
    // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
    // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                               /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account 'null' and 'undefined'. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when 'this' is given the type 'any'. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Default catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when local variables aren't read. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read. */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Add 'undefined' to a type when accessed using an index. */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type. */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */

    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

Using the modules with node and commonjs works fine. I tried using es6 AMD UMD and other ESM and nothing.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).